# Byte Code Verification failing with java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 11 . What does branch target 11 means?

Tags: java, bytecode

Java 1.8 byte code verification is failing when Class is getting loaded.Below is the Constructor of the Class SnaControl which fails to get load. It was working fine when compiled using javac 1.6

```
public com.lucent.oms.sna.SnaControl();
descriptor: ()V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: aload_0
     1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     4: aload_0
     5: aconst_null
     6: putfield      #2                  // Field snaName:Ljava/lang/String;
     9: aload_0
    10: iconst_0
    11: putfield      #3                  // Field snaHealthStatus:Z
    14: aload_0
    15: aconst_null
    16: putfield      #4                  // Field snaPOA:Lorg/omg/PortableServer/POA;
    19: aload_0
    20: aconst_null
    21: putfield      #5                  // Field m_corbaUtil:Lcom/lucent/oms/almapapi/util/CorbaUtil;
    24: aload_0
    25: aconst_null
    26: putfield      #6                  // Field exSnmp:Lcom/lucent/oms/exsnmp/ExSnmpAdapter;
    29: aload_0
    30: putstatic     #7                  // Field snaControlObj:Lcom/lucent/oms/sna/SnaControl;
    33: return
  LineNumberTable:
    line 35: 0
    line 25: 4
    line 26: 9
    line 28: 14
    line 32: 19
    line 33: 24
    line 36: 29
    line 37: 33
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0      34     0  this   Lcom/lucent/oms/sna/SnaControl;
```

ERROR :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap
frame at branch target 11 Exception Details:   Location:
    com/lucent/oms/sna/SnaControl.<init>()V @4: ifnonnull   Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.   Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b201 7b59 c700 0757 b801 8503 324c 2ab7
    0x0000010: 0001 2a01 b500 022a 03b5 0003 2a01 b500
    0x0000020: 042a 01b5 0005 2a01 b500 062a b300 072b
    0x0000030: 0304 54b1
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
   at com.lucent.oms.infra.SubsysCtrl.GenericSubsysCtrlHandler.<init>(GenericSubsysCtrlHandler.java:50)
   at com.lucent.oms.infra.SubsysCtrl.SubsysCtrlHandler.<init>(SubsysCtrlHandler.java:36)
   at com.lucent.oms.infra.SubsysCtrl.SimpleSubsystem.initSubsysCtrlHandler(SimpleSubsystem.java:300)
   at com.lucent.oms.infra.SubsysCtrl.SimpleSubsystem.<init>(SimpleSubsystem.java:228)
   at com.lucent.oms.infra.SubsysCtrl.SimpleSubsystem.main(SimpleSubsystem.java:1442)
```

Comment: How did you get this bytecode? From a compiler? Which one? Which version? From a bytecode generator tool? Which one? Which version? What did you do to get this bytecode? Etc. etc.

Comment: The byte code was generated using javac 1.8 compiler . I need help in understanding what branch target 11 means in this case .

Comment: The disassembly output is not helpful as it is not showing the problematic code. The `VerifyError` refers to `SnaControl.<init>()V`, which is a constructor of the class `SnaControl` having no parameters. It has nothing to do with a method named `init` that takes a `String`. Note further, that the offending byte code has been included in the message as hex dump. There you see that it has 52 bytes, thus it’s a different method than the one you have disassembled which has a size of 270 bytes.

Comment: Thanks Holger , i got confused as init method was prsent in my class.   The problematic byte code is .

Comment: Well, I have an answer, but the question has to get reopened first…

Comment: Hi Simze , Maroun , Edchum , Pietu1998 , greg-449 . can you please remove the question on hold as requirement is clear. The answer will help in understanding the byte code type verification.

Answer (score 1):

The `VerifyError` includes the offending byte code as hex dump. When I decode it, I get:

```
  0 getstatic   [379]
  3 dup
  4 ifnonnull   @7
  7 pop
  8 invokestatic    [389]
 11 iconst_0
 12 aaload
 13 astore_1

 14 aload_0
 15 invokespecial   [1]
 18 aload_0
 19 aconst_null
 20 putfield    [2]
 23 aload_0
 24 iconst_0
 25 putfield    [3]
 28 aload_0
 29 aconst_null
 30 putfield    [4]
 33 aload_0
 34 aconst_null
 35 putfield    [5]
 38 aload_0
 39 aconst_null
 40 putfield    [6]
 43 aload_0
 44 putstatic   [7]

 47 aload_1
 48 iconst_0
 49 iconst_1
 50 bastore
 51 return
```

which obviously differs from the original code you have posted, but in a recognizable pattern. I inserted empty lines to make it easier to recognize your original code within the new code. It’s obvious that your code has been instrumented by a tool adding an action on method entry and method exit.

The problem is that your original code was branch-free whereas the new code contains a conditional branch from position `4` to position `11` (`4+7`). You should recognize these parts in the `VerifyError`’s message: “*Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target* `11`” and “`@4: ifnonnull`”. So the error doesn’t lie in your original code but in the code injected by a byte code instrumentation tool.

Starting with class files `v51` (Java 7), stackmaps became mandatory while for `v50` (Java 6) the verifier switches over to the old legacy verifier if an error with these stackmaps occurs. This was intended to provide time for updating tools, which cannot deal with stackmaps, but instead caused more unawareness regarding this inability.

So what are the practical consequences? You have to identify the tool which performed the invalid instrumentation and update it (hoping that an update exist). This might include frameworks responsible for resource injection, AOP or profiling. Usually, these tools settle on a lower level byte code engineering library, and it might be sufficient to update that library only. Well, if you identified the responsible library you may search for “library name + java8 problems” to find more specific solutions.